# Julia v1.1: create an array of matrices

Tags: matrix, julia, matrix-multiplication, scalar

I'm attempting to create an array of matrices by multiplying a `t = range(0,stop=2*pi,length=101)` by a matrix `[1, 0]` as follows

```
A = t .* [1 ,0]
```

but this produces the error `ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size")`. I would like each scalar, or element of `t` to be multiplied elementwise (in terms of `t`) with the elements of the vector `[1 , 0]`, essentially performing an elementwise scalar--matrix product.

The reason I'm doing this is because I would later like to be able to multiply another constant matrix `M` with each column vector found in `A`. How can this be done in Julia v1.1?

Comment: `[1, 0]` is not a matrix, it's a vector, so you're attempting to multiply two vectors of different lengths with each other, and that won't work. If you want a matrix, write `[1 0]` without a comma. But then the output of the multiplication will just be a matrix, not an array of matrices.

Comment: I guess the question asked for what I discuss in my answer (I am not 100% sure though). @SeSodesa - for a reference: matrix is always 2-dimensional array in Julia terminology. 1-dimensional arrays are called vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the element you do not want to be broadcasted over in a container. Here is a standard way to do it (I decreased `length` kwarg to `3` to make the example more clear):

```
julia> t = range(0,stop=2*pi,length=3)
0.0:3.141592653589793:6.283185307179586

julia> A = t .* Ref([1 ,0])
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [0.0, 0.0]
 [3.141592653589793, 0.0]
 [6.283185307179586, 0.0]

julia> Ref([1 2; 3 4]) .* A
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [0.0, 0.0]
 [3.141592653589793, 9.42477796076938]
 [6.283185307179586, 18.84955592153876]
```

Instead of `Ref` container you can also use a 1-element tuple or 1-element vector as wrappers:

```
julia> t .* ([1 ,0],)
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [0.0, 0.0]
 [3.141592653589793, 0.0]
 [6.283185307179586, 0.0]

julia> t .* [[1 ,0]]
3-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [0.0, 0.0]
 [3.141592653589793, 0.0]
 [6.283185307179586, 0.0]
```

The reason why `Ref` should be preferred is that it is 0-dimensional, so that it is the most neutral of these three methods (i.e. influences the output in the least way - retaining the broadcast style of the other argument). Here are some examples:

```
julia> f1(x) = x .* (2, )
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(x) = x .* [2]
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f3(x) = x .* Ref(2)
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f1(1)
(2,)

julia> f2(1)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2

julia> f3(1)
2

julia> f1((1,2))
(2, 4)

julia> f2((1,2))
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4

julia> f3((1,2))
(2, 4)
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was going for. Now I just have the issue that the resulting array contains a bunch of 1-dimensional arrays, and the matrix `M` I'm trying to multiply each of these with if a `2x2` matrix, so I'm once again faced with a dimension mismatch.

Comment: See my example above. I have shown you how to do it already. replace `[1 2; 3 4]` with `M` and you will get what you wanted. I am assuming that you want to do matrix multiplication (not broadcasted multiplication) - right?

Comment: I would like to do broadcasted matrix multiplication. So essentially `A` should contain `2x1` column vectors, and each of these should be multiplied (in the matrix sense) with  `M`. The result should be a vector of of the matrix multiplication results, of equal length to `A`.

Comment: If you wanted broadcasted multiplication do `[M .* v for v in A]` or `broadcast.(*, Ref(M), A)`. In general - please try asking the initial questions precisely (I know it is sometimes hard though :)) then it is easier to answer them the way you expect. If you want standard multiplication - do what I have suggested above `Ref(M) .* A`.